# Need someone to update these out-of-date MySQL commands(Error: near 'USING BTREE )

Tags: mysql

I need to run these MySQL queries on my server but I'm getting an error

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE "

Here are the queries:

```
"CREATE INDEX pphpbb_forums_track_forum_id
  ON phpbb_forums_track
  USING btree
  (forum_id);

CREATE INDEX pphpbb_forums_track_user_id
  ON phpbb_forums_track
  USING btree
  (user_id);

CREATE INDEX phpbb_topics_track_user_id
  ON phpbb_topics_track
  USING btree
  (user_id);
```

"

Comment: -1 simply because of "need someone to..." without any detail of what you've tried (read the manual?).

Answer (score 2):

A quick glance at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html
tells me you swapped (user_id) with Using.

```
CREATE INDEX phpbb_topics_track_user_id
  ON phpbb_topics_track (user_id)
  USING btree;
```

Answer (score 2):

**CREATE INDEX Syntax**

```
CREATE [UNIQUE|FULLTEXT|SPATIAL] INDEX index_name
    [index_type]
    ON tbl_name (index_col_name,...)
    [index_type]
```

so your query should be

```
CREATE INDEX pphpbb_forums_track_forum_id
  ON phpbb_forums_track (forum_id)
  USING btree;

CREATE INDEX pphpbb_forums_track_user_id
  ON phpbb_forums_track (user_id)
  USING btree ;
```